# Angular - function in service not recognizing $resource

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with Angular factory and trying to make a webservice call, but looks like it is not recognizing $resource.

```
.factory('User', function($resource) {
function login() {
  // THIS IS NOT WORKING, how do I make a webservice call from here?
  $resource('/api/user.json', {}, {

      method: 'POST',
      isArray: false

  });

  return true;
}

function logout() {
  return false;
}

return {
  login : function() { return login(); },
  logout: function() { return logout(); }
};
```

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: what's your error message , $resource is not included in the main script you need to import the angular-resource script : angular-resource.js

Comment: Hi @mpm, yes I have angular-resource.js imported. And $resource works. But since I have a function within the factory, I think the scope is messed up and I can't figure out how to allow that login function to be able to access $resource

Comment: then you should correct your question because i dont see query anywhere in your script. Furthermore $resource returns a resource object , you need to actually use the returned of object ot fire a request.

Answer (score 2):

i assume you have the resource module file somewhere :

https://raw.github.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/ngResource/resource.js

you need to import the proper module in your app :

```
var App = angular.module("App",["ngResource"]);
```

then use it in a "sane" way :

```
var User = App.factory("User",function($resource){
    var User = $resource('/api/user.json',{},{
       login:{method:"POST",isArray:true},
       logout:{method:"POST"}
    });
    return User;
    // use User in your controller or another service.
});
```

the doc is here : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource